# Является ли хорошей идеей писать игру на HTML, CSS и JavaScript (не canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, css, разработка-игр, canvas

Является ли хорошей идеей писать игру внутри браузера, используя HTML блоки, настроить их внешний вид на CSS и с помощью JS настроить действия в игре?

Слышал про canvas, но есть ли в нём большая необходимость? Какие проблемы могут возникнуть при написании игры не на canvas? Какие плюсы и минусы?

2D игра, небольшая. Персонаж игрока будет вести диалог с другими персонажами и собирать яблоки

Comment: Если игра "небольшая" то можно всё сделать блоками, но гораздо проще это всё реализовать в Canvas.

Comment: Я пятнашки так писал. Просто html, css, js. Зависит вообше от цели. Если для себя, потренироваться в js - можно. Если для того, чтобы впечатлить каких-либо дядек в компании - можно брать любой игровой движок или с нуля на канвасе.... В общем ответ: зависит... Но вообще для мелочи можно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский но чем собственно так хорош canvas на фоне html, css, js?

Comment: @o_o для больших игр - производительностью, наличием фреймворков и плагинов с готовыми реализациями физики, света и пр + оптимизированностью работы (скорость, расход памяти и пр). Да и на canvas'е гораздо проще что-то нарисовать - например анимированную ломанную линию , которая ползёт вперёд и изгибается как змея... попробуйте так сделать в отрыве от него так)) или любую сложную анимацию.

Comment: @o_o если вы сможете написать адекватный свет, тени, или волнующийся океан - только поаплодирую стоя)

Comment: А в случае webgl canvas можно ещё и шейдерами побаловаться.